# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined/XML

Tags: reactjs

I am calling service that is using XML, so i want to parse XML to JSON and the JSON data set as my react state but i am getting.

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
```

```
axios
  .get(session_url)
  .then(function(response) {
    parseString(response.data, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      } else {
        this.setState({
          odm: result.data,
          loading: false,
        });
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing and matching `function()`s that don't capture `this` and arrow (`=>`) functions which do.

Simply use arrow functions everywhere and the `this` (that's your React component) will be properly captured:

```
axios
  .get(session_url)
  .then(response => {
    parseString(response.data, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      } else {
        this.setState({
          odm: result.data,
          loading: false,
        });
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Better yet, if you can, use an `async` function:

```
// promisified version of `parseString`:
const parseStringP = data =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    parseString(response.data, (err, result) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve(result);
    }),
  );

// ...

try {
  const response = await axios.get(session_url);
  const result = await parseStringP(response.data);

  this.setState({
    odm: result.data,
    loading: false,
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```